# Adding an end screen to a Canvas and jQuery based game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've took a tutorial for a snake game, and I'm trying to make it better for a little side project at the moment. I have a start screen where the user can press start to start the game.

I am trying to add an end screen in when the user dies that it will show up what their score was, and to add in a play button so that the user can hit play without refreshing the browser.

Being new to both jQuery and Canvas, I've struggled with this and tried many different ways to do it. I was wondering what is the best way to going about adding this end screen in.

I have also included a JS Fiddle to show what I'm trying to do.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="SplashScreen">
    <h1>Snake</h1>
    <input class="StartButton" type="button" value="Start" />
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvasArea" width="600" height="450" style="display:none;"></canvas>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".StartButton").click(function () {
$(".SplashScreen").hide();
$("#canvasArea").show();
});


//Canvas stuff
var canvas = $("#canvasArea")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = $("#canvasArea").width();
var h = $("#canvasArea").height();

//Lets save the cell width in a variable for easy control
var sw = 15;
var direction;
var nd;
var food;
var score;

//Lets create the snake now
var snake_array; //an array of cells to make up the snake

function init() {
    direction = "right"; //default direction
    nd = [];
    create_snake();
    create_food(); //Now we can see the food particle
    //finally lets display the score
    score = 0;

    //Lets move the snake now using a timer which will trigger the paint function
    //every 60ms
    if(typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);
}

init();

function create_snake() {
    var length = 5; //Length of the snake
    snake_array = []; //Empty array to start with
    for(var i = length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            //This will create a horizontal snake starting from the top left
            snake_array.push({x: i, y:0});
        }
    }

//Lets create the food now
function create_food() {
    food = {
                x: Math.round(Math.random()*(w-sw)/sw),
                y: Math.round(Math.random()*(h-sw)/sw),
            };
            //This will create a cell with x/y between 0-44
            //Because there are 45(450/10) positions accross the rows and columns
    }

//Lets paint the snake now
function paint() {
    if (nd.length) {
    direction = nd.shift();
    }

//To avoid the snake trail we need to paint the BG on every frame
//Lets paint the canvas now
ctx.fillStyle = "#8db370";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

//The movement code for the snake to come here.
//The logic is simple
//Pop out the tail cell and place it infront of the head cell
var nx = snake_array[0].x;
var ny = snake_array[0].y;

//These were the position of the head cell.
//We will increment it to get the new head position
//Lets add proper direction based movement now
if(direction == "right") nx++;
else if(direction == "left") nx--;
else if(direction == "up") ny--;
else if(direction == "down") ny++;

//Lets add the game over clauses now
//This will restart the game if the snake hits the wall
//Lets add the code for body collision
//Now if the head of the snake bumps into its body, the game will restart
if(nx == -1 || nx == w/sw || ny == -1 || ny == h/sw || check_collision(nx, ny, snake_array))
    {

    //restart game
    init();

    //Lets organize the code a bit now.
    return;
    }

//Lets write the code to make the snake eat the food
//The logic is simple
//If the new head position matches with that of the food,
//Create a new head instead of moving the tail
if(nx == food.x && ny == food.y)
    {
        var tail = {x: nx, y: ny};
        score++;

        //Create new food
        create_food();
    }

        else

    {
        var tail = snake_array.pop(); //pops out the last cell
        tail.x = nx; tail.y = ny;

    }

    //The snake can now eat the food.
    snake_array.unshift(tail); //puts back the tail as the first cell

    for(var i = 0; i < snake_array.length; i++)
    {
        var c = snake_array[i];

        //Lets paint 10px wide cells
        paint_cell(c.x, c.y);
    }

    //Lets paint the food
    paint_cell(food.x, food.y);

    //Lets paint the score
    var score_text = "Score: " + score;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(score_text, 5, h-5);

    //Set the font and font size
    ctx.font = '12pt Arial';

    //position of the fill text counter
    ctx.fillText(itemCounter, 10, 10);

    }

//Lets first create a generic function to paint cells
function paint_cell(x, y)
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#5c7f3d";
        ctx.fillRect(x*sw, y*sw, sw, sw);
    }

function check_collision(x, y, array)
    {
        //This function will check if the provided x/y coordinates exist
        //in an array of cells or not
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                if(array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y)
                return true;
            }

        return false;
    }

    //Lets add the keyboard controls now
$(document).keydown(function(e){
var key = e.which;
var td;
if (nd.length) {
    var td = nd[nd.length - 1];

} else {
    td = direction;
}

//We will add another clause to prevent reverse gear
if(key == "37" && td != "right") nd.push("left");
else if(key == "38" && td != "down") nd.push("up");
else if(key == "39" && td != "left") nd.push("right");
else if(key == "40" && td != "up") nd.push("down");

//The snake is now keyboard controllable

})

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LsGW4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things. Remove the `init()` on line 39. This will stop the snake game from starting till ready. (add `init()` to the click callback).

Then add a function which does the reverse of the click callback to show the first screen with the start button. call it in the end game section instead of init.

Then you can add some content changes to show the score.

Here is an updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/sxaN3/) showing this.

```
function endGame() {
    $("#canvasArea").hide();
    $("#score").text(score);
    $(".FinishScreen").show();
}
```

Comment: awesome! thanks for the help really appreciate it, canvas is difficult to get started on.